# Como guardar una tabla pivot con multiples relaciones usando Eloquent en Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy trabajando con laravel 8, me causa la duda de cómo guardar esos datos en mi pivot del usuario de la tabla dinámica

```
class User extends Authenticatable
```

{

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'contracts');
}

public function offices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class,'contracts');
}
```

}

Existe una relación de muchos a muchos entre roles y oficinas que me proporciona una tabla dinámica como esta:

```
Table Name: contracts
Colums:
id
user_id
office_id
role_id.
```

Y lo intenté de esta manera, pero solo me guarda los datos del usuario, pero en la tabla dinámica no hace nada me sale error en la sincronización

```
  public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
{
  
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'document' => $request->document,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    $user->roles()->sync([$request->role_id, ['office_id' => $request->office_id]]);
    // $user->roles()->attach($request->role_id,['office_id'=>$request->office_id]);
    // $user = $this->userRepository->create($input);
    return $this->sendResponse($user->toArray(), 'User saved successfully');
}
```

Cuando envio data dd($request->all()); me envia estos datos

```
array: 6 ["name" => "444"
"document" => "42344444"
"email" => "44424@net.com"
"password" => "admin"
"office_id" => array: 2 [0 => array: 2 ["id" => 19
"name" => "SIMULACION"]
1 => array: 2 ["id" => 14
"name" => "PEI 2030"]]
"role_id" => array: 2 [0 => array: 2 ["id" => 2
"name" => "Asistente"]
1 => array: 2 ["id" => 3
"name" => "Director de Oficina"]]]
```

Necesito ayuda.
Este es mi Error

```
message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…} exception: "ErrorException" file: "C:\laragon\www\tramite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php" line: 488 message: "Array to string conversion"
```

Comment: En tu query para el alta mencionas te sale un error, ¿puedes agregar dicho error?

Comment: message: "Array to string conversion", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\laragon\www\tramite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php"
line: 488
message: "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 0):

Te tira error debido a que estás pasando mal los parámetros de la función `sync()` y (también en el caso de `attach()`). Acá tienes la definición de `sync`:

```
/**
 * Sync the intermediate tables with a list of IDs or collection of models.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|array  $ids
 * @param  bool  $detaching
 * @return array
 */
public function sync($ids, $detaching = true) {/** ... */}
```

Si te fijas, verás que espera como primer parámero un modelo o un array y como segundo parámetro un `boolean`. Este arreglo que se pasa como primer parámetro, puede ser unidimensional (de ids) o uno asociativo en el cual las llaves sirven como ids y los valores como data adicional a almacenar en la tabla pivote.

En cambio, estás pasando un arreglo que contiene, a su vez, otros dos arreglos:

```
$user->roles()->sync([
    [
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "Asistente"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "name" => "Director de Oficina"
        ],
    ],
    [
        'office_id' => [
            [
                "id" => 19,
                "name" => "SIMULACION"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 14,
                "name" => "PEI 2030"
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

No tan similar, no es así? Es debido a esto que te tira el error de conversión.

Dado que tú quieres pasarle varios roles a la vez, y que en cada uno de ellos insertar data adicional, sería conveniente usar el modo de arreglo. Si te fijas en [la documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) verás un ejemplo que puedes utilizar:

> #### Syncing Associations
>
> ...
>
> You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:
>
> ```
> $user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
> ```

Lo que podrías hacer es darle forma para que tome la siguiente estructura (asumiendo que cada rol corresponde a una oficina):

```
$user->roles()->sync([
    2 => ['office_id' => 19],
    3 => ['office_id' => 14],
]);
```

Por último, por el lado lógico, si un usuario puede tener varios roles, y esto es independiente de las oficinas.. quizás puedas almacenar las relaciones en tablas distintas. Pero claro, no conozco toda la idea de tu app para poder aconsejarte mejor.

---

Como nota adicional, la consulta que realizas es independiente de Laravel 8, no ha habido cambios en este aspecto (operaciones con relaciones) desde hace ya unos años.

Comment: foreach ($request->arrayDetalle as $index => $value) {
                $arrayIdOffices[$value["office_id"]] = ['role_id' => $value["role_id"]];
                 array_push($arrayIdRoles,$arrayIdOffices);
            }
            dd($arrayIdOffices,$arrayIdRoles);
            $userUpdate->offices()->sync($arrayIdOffices);

Comment: array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "role_id" => 4
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    1 => array:1 [
      "role_id" => 3
    ]
  ]
]   como haria para que solo me tome el valor de esos arrays  ese es el resultado